# Limits calculation approaches not given the same result

Tags: calculus, limits

Friends, I was given a limit to calculate but it is not intuitive for me, if I solve it algebraically, it gives me 0, but if I take an analytical approach it gives infinity. Can you guys tell me how I can solve this on a algebraic matter?

The limit goes like:

[image]

The f(x) graph plotted:

[image]

Comment: Is that the limit as $x \to 1-$ of the radical, or is that the limit as $x \to 1$ of (-1) times the radical?

Answer (score 2):

Is that the limit as x goes to 1 from the left? The limit does not exist. I think your graph is wrong. We get the graph going to positive infinity at the positive root of $x^2+4x-3$ which $\sqrt{7}-2$.

The function is undefined over $[\sqrt{7}-2,1)$ (over the reals) because we have square root of a negative. So we have an undefined limit from 1-. The limit isn't positive or negative $\infty$ either.

We can't plug in $x=1$ because the function is not continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @Ammet Sharma, thank you for your answer, I understood there is an asymptote on the graph, thank you! I just wonder why when I calculate it algebraically, it gives zero (using the standard procedure: seeing if after replacing the limit in the f(x) I come across a indetermination and if not, evaluate the expression with the limit)

Comment: The function is one-sided continuous at $x=1$. It is continuous from the right only. So therefore plugging in 1 will give you the 1+ limit, not the 1- limit.